# How to access nested object value

Tags: javascript, object

```
var allowed_ids = {
            332438809: "Bereznyak24",
            about: {
                address: "Gorky 84",
                average_sum: 50
            },
            489485425: "Bereznyak25",
            about: {
                address: "Sohnstr 41",
                average_sum: 100
            }
        };


var checked = childs[0].innerHTML.replace(/\D+/g, "");
console.log(allowed_ids.checked.about.address);
```

`

In checked variable I store either 332438809 or 489485425. Saying `allowed_ids[checked]` results in Bereznyak24 or Bereznyak 25. But how can I access `address` and `average_sum` values?
`allowed_ids.checked.about.address` this piece of code is a wrong one and does not result in a proper responce. Thanks!

Comment: Your given object has duplicate keys `about` which overwrite the first one

Comment: Are you able to re-write the object so it will work as you need or are you stuck with that object?

Comment: @imvain2 can do so. What's the proper way to reorganize it?

Answer (score 1):

`allowed_ids` needs to be an array, otherwise you are overwriting the `about` key each subsequent time you assign it.

```
var allowed_ids = [
{
  332438809: "Bereznyak24",
  about: {
    address: "Gorky 84",
    average_sum: 50
  }
},
{
  489485425: "Bereznyak25",
  about: {
    address: "Sohnstr 41",
    average_sum: 100
  }
}];


var checked = childs[0].innerHTML.replace(/\D+/g, "");
console.log(allowed_ids[checked].about.address);
```

Comment: This is wrong OP Said _"In `checked` variable I store either `332438809` or `489485425`"_. And `allowed_ids[checked]` will return `undefined`. There is no reason to create array.

Comment: Then op should mark https://stackoverflow.com/a/55500297/6301806 as correct

Answer (score 1):

Your object is not correct. You should use `332438809,489485425` as keys and store `"Bereznyak24","Bereznyak25"` as property of nested object. And use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access dynamic property names

```js
var allowed_ids = {
            332438809:{
              name:"Bereznyak24",
              address: "Gorky 84",
              average_sum: 50
            },
            489485425:{
                name:"Bereznyak25",
                address: "Sohnstr 41",
                average_sum: 100
            }
        };


var checked = '332438809';
console.log(allowed_ids[checked].address);
console.log(allowed_ids[checked].name);
console.log(allowed_ids[checked].average_sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object has duplicate keys. It would be better to store it like this:

```
var allowed_ids = {
            332438809:{
             name: "Bereznyak24",
             about: {
                address: "Gorky 84",
                average_sum: 50
              }
            },
            489485425: {
             name:  "Bereznyak25",
             about: {
                address: "Sohnstr 41",
                average_sum: 100
             }
           }
        };
```

```
// Assuming checked = 489485425
console.log(allowed_ids[checked].about.address)
// Result = Sohnstr 41
```

Comment: If this is what `checked` represents then this is more correct than my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 489485425 and 332438809 are your keys, you can do as follows.

```js
var allowed_ids = {
            332438809: {
                name: "Bereznyak24",
                address: "Gorky 84",
                average_sum: 50
            },
            489485425: {
                name: "Bereznyak25",
                address: "Sohnstr 41",
                average_sum: 100
            }
        };
        
        
        console.log(allowed_ids[489485425].name);
        console.log(allowed_ids[489485425].address);
        console.log(allowed_ids[489485425].average_sum);
```